# OKHTTP : how to catch the EBADF exception

Tags: android, okhttp

Using OkHTTP in my Android app, I have a lot of exception :
EX:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getsockname failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.getSocketLocalPort(IoBridge.java:649)
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.closeSocket(IoBridge.java:202)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.close(PlainSocketImpl.java:162)
       at ...
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getsockname failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
       at libcore.io.Posix.getsockname(Posix.java)
       at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getsockname(ForwardingOs.java:69)
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.getSocketLocalPort(IoBridge.java:645)
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.closeSocket(IoBridge.java:202)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.close(PlainSocketImpl.java:162)
       at java.net.Socket.close(Socket.java:319)
       at ...
```

I can't catch this error because it's inside the OkHTTP library.

Any solution for me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discuss with the OkHttp Team, And now the fix is inside the current release !

OkHttp v2.5.0

OkIO v1.6.0

More information here : 
https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/1817

Root cause is a android 4 bug :
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54072